# Why do I keep gettting an first use of this function error even though I wrote char answer at the top?

Tags: c, while-loop, do-while

I tried every single solution I have found to fix that problem but non helped me. I also tried without do-while, with `while (true)` but couldn't make it either. My error:

```
error: ‘answer’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   30 |  }while (answer == 'n' || answer == 'N');
      |          ^~~~~~
```

.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
        do {
        double length;
        char unit;
        char answer;
        printf("Enter the length: ");
        scanf("%lf%c", &length, &unit);
        if (unit == 'i' || unit == 'I')
        {
                printf("%1.2lf i = %lf c \n", length, 2.54*length);
        }
        else if (unit == 'm' || unit == 'M')
        {
                printf("%1.2lf i = %lf c \n", 39.3701*length, 100*length);
        }
        else if (unit == 'c' || unit == 'C')
        {
                printf("%1.2lf i = %lf c \n", length/2.54, length);
        }
        else
        {
                printf("0 i = 0 c");
        }

        printf("Do you want to start over? y/n \n");
        scanf("%c", & answer);
        answer = getchar();
        }while (answer == 'n' || answer == 'N');

        return 1;
}
```

Comment: Because `answer` is local to the scope *within* the `do..while` block

Comment: `answer` is destroyed before it is checked in the `while` condition. After all, the `}` _does_ come before `while()`

Comment: Aside: why does the code read a character into `answer` using `scanf` and then immediately overwrite it with `answer = getchar();`?

Comment: @IanAbbott It didn't work without getchar() function. & getchar() is used to read data from the keyboard. I changed the code from answer = getchar(); to just getchar(); by the way

Answer (score 0):

`char answer;` is inside the `do { ... } while();` loop and the scope is restricted to inside the curly brackets. You therefore cannot access `answer` in `while()` condition. which is outside the curly brackets.